# Add two MutableList in android

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin

I wonder why totalList will display null. i have 2 MutableList

```
var totalList  : MutableList<String>?=null
var listOfImagesPath: MutableList<String>? = null
```

The `listOfImagesPath` will used to retrieve all the image from phone. I would like to add the `listOfImagesPath` to `totalList`

```
listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath()
totalList?.add(listOfImagesPath.toString())
```

I check their size using below code

```
longToast("list" +listOfImagesPath?.size.toString())
longToast("total "+totalList?.size.toString())
```

**Output**

```
5
null
```

Why I will get null ?

**Edit**

What I would like to achieve is the captured image and image selected from gallery get display into gridView.

**CameraCapture**

```
 listOfImagesPath?.clear()
 listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath()
 totalList?.addAll(listOfImagesPath!!)
 grid.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(this, totalList))
```

**Pick image from gallery**

```
   val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity()?.getContentResolver(), uri);
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)
    val path = getRealPathFromURI(uri)
    listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath()
      if(listOfImagesPath?.size!=0){
         totalList.addAll(listOfImagesPath!!)
     }
      totalList.add(path)
      grid.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(this, totalList))
```

Issue now is when I capture one image, it works fine. But when I capture  image second time, it display 3 images (1st,1st and 2nd). It seems like the `totalList` is added twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first initialize your list like this

```
var totalList MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

and then just add new value to it normally

```
totalList.add(listOfImagesPath.toString())
```

Comment: thanks. Can't I just add listOfImagesPath instead of listOfImagesPath.toString()?

Comment: `listOfImagesPath` is a list so I guess not. If you want to add all values of `listOfImagesPath` into `totalList`, then you need to use `addAll`: `totalList.addAll(listOfImagesPath)`

Comment: Can you check my post again ?

Comment: It can be that `listOfImagesPath` also contains `getRealPathFromURI`, have you tried logging paths of `listOfImagesPath` and `val path`?